# TextBox values are not updated from external method?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a simple GUI with 6 textboxes.

I have a method that takes 7 parameters, 1 being a long string and the other 6 being the textboxes.  The method looks like this:

```
SetTextBoxesFromTokens(string s, string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, string f)
{
string[] tokens = s.Split('-');

a = tokens[0];
b = tokens[1];
c = tokens[2];
d = tokens[3];
e = tokens[4];
f = tokens[5];
}
```

I am calling the above method like so, but it is not updating the text boxes:

```
SetTextBoxesFromTokens("1-2-3-4-5-6",
        txtA.Text,txtB.Text,txtC.Text,txtD.Text,txtE.Text,txtF.Text);
```

Comment: Genuinely surprised to see you have a such a high score and your previous questions are very good, but still come up with such a question...  Please revisit the Method parameter section with most importantly "Pass by value and Pass by reference" section.

Comment: Well, I did try passing my ref, but I was doing ref txtA.Text and it was giving me an error.

Answer (score 3):

The values are passed by value i.e. [**parameter passing of value types**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) i.e a new variable is created for parameter and text of textbox is copied to it. Change of value of parameter is not supposed to be reflected in text boxes. If you want to change the value of textboxes in the function the pass the TextBoxes objects instead of Text.

```
SetTextBoxesFromTokens(string s, TextBox txta, TextBox txtb, TextBox txtc, TextBox txtd, TextBox txte, TextBox txtf)
{    
  string[] tokens = s.Split('-');

  txta.Text = tokens[0];
  txtb.Text  = tokens[1];
  txtc.Text  = tokens[2];
  txtd.Text  = tokens[3];
  txte.Text  = tokens[4];
  txtf.Text  = tokens[5];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying this, but I was passing `txtA.Text` by ref, but that gave me an error.

Comment: There is a slight problem I have, the assembly were `SetTextBoxesFromTokens` is declared can't have any references to `UI` stuff like TextBoxes, so how could I work around it?

Comment: Why the assembly could not have reference to UI stuff?

Answer (score 2):

When calling your method, a copy of the string is created.  This means that you're not assigning your array of tokens to the .Text property of the respective TextBox controls.  You're just assigning values to things that'll fall out of scope at the end of the block.

You will be far better served with a more appropriate data structure for your requirement.

Consider instead:-

```
SetTextBoxesFromTokens(Dictionary<string,TextBox> tokenDict) 
{
  tokenDict
    .Keys
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(k => tokenDict[k].Text = k);
}
```

Call it like so:-

```
// Define key value pair set containing
// token
// textbox to set
var dict = new Dictionary<string,TextBox>()
  {
    { "a", txtA },
    { "b", txtB },
    { "c", txtC }, 
    { "d", txtD },
    { "e", txtE },
    { "f", txtF }
  };

SetTextBoxesFromTokens(dict);
```

Using this approach, the `Dictionary<string,TextBox>` parameter ( and the `TextBox` objects within ) are passed by reference, and your method is no longer tied to a specific number of `TextBox`, or a coupled `string.Split` implementation which breaks if there aren't enough tokens.